# Building a sharded list in Google App Engine

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, sharding

I am looking for a good design pattern for sharding a list in Google App Engine.  I have read about and implemented sharded counters as described in the Google Docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters?csw=1) but I am now trying to apply the same principle to a list.  Below is my problem and possible solution - please can I get your input?

Problem:
A user on my system could receive many messages kind of like a online chat system.  I'd like the server to record all incoming messages (they will contain several fields - from, to, etc).  However, I know from the docs that updating the same entity group often can result in an exception caused by datastore contention.  This could happen when one user receives many messages in a short time thus causing his entity to be written to many times.  So what about abstracting out the sharded counter example above:

- Define say five entities/entity groups
- for each message to be added, pick one entity at random and append the message to it writing it back to the store,
- To get list of messages, read all entities  in and merge...

Ok some questions on the above:

1. Most importantly, is this the best way to go about things or is there a more elegant/more efficient  design pattern?
2. What would be a efficient  way to filter the list of messages by one of the fields say everything after a certain date?
3. What if I require a sharded set instead?   Should I read in all entities and check if the new item already exists on every write?  Or just add it as above and then remove duplicates whenever the next request comes in to read?

Answer (score 0):

why would you want to put all messages in 1 entity group ?

If you don't specify a ancestor, you won't need sharding, but the end user might see some lagging when querying the messages due to eventual consistency.

Depends if that is an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: I wasn' planning on putting all messages in one entity group, I am worried about what happens when one user receives too many messages such that there is contention on his entity.

Comment: well, you will get exceptions saying 'too much contention'. it is better to design against this then to deal with it.

Comment: I think I see your confusion : same entity <> same entity group