# Modeling a system with users who can send messages to each other in GAE datastore

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, modeling

I was wondering whether you could help me work out a way to model the following in a GAE datastore such that it is scalable and can be updated frequently.  I thought I had a solution which I expressed in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441311/building-a-sharded-list-in-google-app-engine/27443729?noredirect=1)  but whilst waiting for replies I realise that it might be overly complicated.  I have explained below why I have kept it as a separate question.

Problem:
Building a system with users who can send many messages to each other.  Each user must be able to retrieve their messages - like online chat.  Would like to avoid contention when possibly a user may receive many messages over a short time.

Solution 1:
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441311/building-a-sharded-list-in-google-app-engine/27443729?noredirect=1) I am wondering whether a sharded list can be used to implement this.  By this I mean have messages stored as entity objects and sender and receiver store the keys of these objects (the messages sent between them) in a list.  I thought of sharding because  a user who receives many messages would have to update the list frequently and a sharding approach could have prevented datastore contention.

Problem - what happens when the list of keys to say a user's received messages   gets large?  Will appending to it not become slow?  I could split the list over several entities but this would take careful thought on allocation schemes and ways of retrieval.   Willing to do this if it is the best way.

Alternative approach:
Store messages as entity objects (as above) but this time have them store a properties which are indexed (date, from, to, etc). Retrieve messages for a user using queries (date greater than..., from=... etc).   This could work well but I worry - will all the indexing degrade as they will grow extremely large with many users sending many messages?  Seems like it will degrade into an SQL like system.

Any thoughts?

I have read about how to model complex relations in the GAE docs but they are using python for an example and I am having trouble abstracting the overall design pattern.

Many thanks to anyone with input on this

PS at the moment  using the low level datastore directly.

Comment: accept that whatever you do the first time will probably be wrong. Use tests to determine if your solution meets your requirements. Don't worry about the "size" of the index - that's GAE's job

Comment: I would say one message is one entity and have custom index of (user_id, timestamp) based on my experience, I don't like a list of thing that keeps growing (and eventually hit 1mb limit)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a system similar to this before. The way I chose to implement it was that i created a `Conversation` entity, that was the parent for many `Message` entities. A conversation had two participants (although you could do more), each of which was the key to a `User` entity.

Something like this (assuming ofy)

```
@Entity public class Conversation {
    @Id Long id;
    @Index Key<User> participant1;
    @Index Key<User> participant2;
    @Index String participant1ExternalId;
    @Index String participant2ExternalId;
}

@Entity public class Message {
    @Id Long id;
    @Parent Ref<Conversation> conversation;
    @Index String senderExternalId;
    @Index String recipientExternalId;
    String message;        
}
```

In this way, you can query all conversations for a participant in an eventually consistent fashion, and all messages received or sent (or both) for a conversation in a strongly consistent fashion. I had an extra requirement of users not being able to identify eachother, and so messaging used generated UUIDs (the externalId properties).

So in this way, sharding and the 1 write/sec limit applies at a conversation level. You could put unread counters onto the conversation object for each user, or on each message if you needed to (at a contention level it makes no real difference, so whatever makes most sense).

If your users are regularly exceeding 1 message per second per conversation you'll have a lot of other problems to solve beyond just datastore contention, so its probably a good starting point. In the general case, eventual consistency will work very well for this sort of operation (i.e. checking for new messages), so you can lean heavily on that.